# How can I get the return value of minions that not connected?

Tags: python, salt-stack

I was using [Saltstack's python api](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clients/index.html#python-api) to execute salt command and the code lists below.

```
local = salt.client.LocalClient()
local.cmd(['node1', 'node2', 'node3'], 'cp.get_file', ['salt://file', '/root/file'], expr_form='list')
```

Minion node3 was not connected to the Master, but the return value of node3 was not shown in the results.

```
{'node1': '/root/file', 'node2': '/root/file'}
```

But if I run `salt 'node[1-3]' cp.get_file salt://file /root/file` in the shell, the results of node3 should be: `node3: Minion did not return. [No response]`
So how can I get the results of node3 when I use Salt's python api?

### Thx guys.

Comment: Please post different and unrelated questions in different posts.

Answer (score 1):

According to source code (`salt/client/__init__.py`) this behaviour is specific to cli invocation only. So i believe it is impossible to get the same output format using python API.

However, usually this is not needed. Given you have a list of target minions, it's easy to find what minions did not respond:

```
local = salt.client.LocalClient()
target = ['node1', 'node2', 'node3']
ret = local.cmd(target, 'cp.get_file', ['salt://file', '/root/file'], expr_form='list')
fails = list(set(target) - set(ret))
```